# Checking out another branches file(s)

Tags: git

I am working in a branch separate from the main development branch in a GitHub repository.

I was informed that the file I was going to need work on had been updated and I need to pull it into my branch

I found the syntax: `git checkout <branch_name> -- <paths>`

However when I try to call it like so:

```
git checkout <branch name> -- /CompanyName/ProductName
```

I am getting the error:

```
error: Invalid path 'build/public/bruno-magli-raging-slip-on-loafers?ID=449656'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you have to pull the master branch (like `git pull origin master`) and then merge it into your 'feature'-branch or to rebase the 'feature'-branch onto master

Comment: That's basically that is going on, except there are multiple people working on different feature branches and I need to pull one of the files they committed to master back to me.

Comment: Is it actual name for a file containing `loafers?ID=449656`? If so, I doubt you could checkout such file on a Windows.

Comment: what git version are you using?

Comment: Likely some of your peers have committed a file which can't be easily checked out on Windows due to filesystem restrictions (a typical file systems in a unix-like system has lesser restriction on filenames). So you should ask them rename the file in the master.

Comment: ... and certianly, you should use `git pull` to `fetch` and `merge` their changes to your tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a clean directory (`git status`) and then get the latest from the branch you need, probably master:

```
$ git checkout master # switch to the master branch
$ git pull origin # Get latest
```

## Option 1: Rebase

Apply the changes from master and put your changes on top:

```
$ git rebase master feature/your-feature-branch
```

## Option 2: Merge

Switch to your feature branch:

```
$ git checkout feature/your-feature-branch
```

Apply the latest from master on top of your feature branch:

```
$ git merge master
```